# Can I use a reflexive ACL in place of a Firewall?

Tags: cisco, acl, firewall

I'm studying CCNA and i've just learnt about Reflexive ACL's. Just wondering how secure or insecure it would be to use an ACL in place of a firewall.

This was a LAB router that I would like to set up as my home internet gateway.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, you can use a reflexive ACL but it couldn't possibly be as secure as a stateful inspection firewall.  Since you are studying for the CCNA, you should build the lab network like real customers do. IOS has a [real stateful inspection fw](http://www.cisco.com/en/US/products/sw/secursw/ps1018/index.html); I would use that.

Comment: Thank you, I didn't realise that was in all IOS images.

Comment: which version and feature set are you using?

Comment: @Mokilok it isnt in every IOS images - you need to use the feature navigator to check as Mike is referencing to.

Comment: My image is c1841-ipbase-mz.124-3i.bin

I'm guessing that since it's ipbase I don't have access to the firewall.

Comment: Correct, in most cases you will require AdvIPservices IOS to utilise the IP Inspect features. It is very powerful, don't forget by default it hates Java - http://www.cisco.com/en/US/docs/ios-xml/ios/sec_data_cbac_fw/configuration/15-mt/config-cbac-fw.html#GUID-0A32029A-3D69-4AD1-8084-A472B539556C